# AND && OR || combination in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Task explained shortly:
Making a datingsite, that need 4 outcomes. Woman 25 and above, Woman 24 and below. Man 25 and above, Woman 24 and below. Now I want to have 4 more outcomes; all womans, all men, all 25 and above, all 24 and below.

I just started on my bachelor degree in August and have not coded anything before.
I am now working on a few tasks that we got, this is a task that we had to deliver that was work requierment. I delivered it with arrays and got the job done with it, and with one else if statement more. Everything good so far.
But now later on, we just learned about object literals, and I wanted to check if I could do the code somehow shorter. I actually did with only 1x if statement below.

I am struggling with OR || and && combinations. I've seen some threads on it, saying that parantheses should be placed before and after &&, but I can't seem to get it. The below code does work with the 4 possible combinations, I wanted to check if someone can see how I can add || && combinations more smarter to get the 4 more combinations that I want, in the same if-statement? Or do I have to make a new else if statement?
Also, how would you solve this, what type of storing variables would you go for?
I have thougth about using some parameters in the function, to shorten something, but I could not come up with something, yet.

```
var result = document.getElementById('result');
var searchBtn = document.getElementById('search-btn');


var data = {
    profiles: 
    [{
        name: 'Maren',
        age: 26,
        gender: 'female',
        description: 'If you do not like me, I will be attracted by you.',
        image: 'kvinne1.jpg'
    }, {
        name: 'Indie',
        age: 23,
        gender: 'female',
        description: 'Love flowers',
        image: 'kvinne2.jpg'
    }, {
        name: 'Felix',
        age: 22,
        gender: 'male',
        description: 'Snowboard, that is lyfe',
        image: 'mann2.jpg'
    }, {
        name: 'Jon',
        age: 26,
        gender: 'male',
        description: 'Love to fish, and I will learn you to fish if you want!',
        image: 'mann1.jpg'
    }]
};



function getResult() {
    result.innerHTML = '';

    var ageInput = document.getElementById('age-input').value;
    var genderInput = document.getElementById('gender-input').value.toLowerCase();
    
    for (let i = 0; i < data.profiles.length; i++) {
        if ((genderInput === data.profiles[i].gender) && (ageInput < 25) && (data.profiles[i].age < 25) || (genderInput === data.profiles[i].gender) && (ageInput >= 25) && (data.profiles[i].age >= 25)) {
            result.innerHTML += `
                <img src='${data.profiles[i].image}'>
                <h2>${data.profiles[i].name}</h2>
                <p>Age: ${data.profiles[i].age}</p>
                <p>${data.profiles[i].description}</p>
                <hr>
                `;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: OK. If I want a new "rule" statement after the first if-line there, can I separate that whole and add a new || with then parantheses with a new and/or sentence? Like 
if (genderInput === data.profiles[i].gender && (ageInput < 25 && data.profiles[i].age < 25 || genderInput === data.profiles[i].gender && ageInput >= 25 && data.profiles[i].age >= 25)(NEW && || STATEMENTS HERE)), is that possible?

Comment: in that case i'd advise wrapping in parenthesis to be clear what you are comparing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have one common part with gender and another with age which is either smaller than `25` or equal or greater than `25`.

You need no parenthese around comparisons.

```
genderInput === data.profiles[i].gender && 
(ageInput < 25 && data.profiles[i].age < 25 || ageInput >= 25 && data.profiles[i].age >= 25)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for clearing that up. So I only need the age sentence in parantheses like you have it there, because there is one OR || in between the two AND && statements? And if I would have more genders i.e., then I could have those two gendertypes in another paranthese like the ages? Hope I could make my question clear enough for you to understand it. Also, would you use objects with arrays to store thath kind of Data, or would you use anything else more smart probably?

Comment: ad1: yes. the structure is `a && (b || c) === a && b || a && c` for transfroming an expression. ad2: no, the data structure is fine.

Answer (score 1):

As per the description, I think you are looking to create different array with some condition if so.

const allMale = data.profiles.filter(profile => profile.gender === 'male') // will give you all men

cont allFemale =data.profiles.filter(profile => profile.gender === 'female' && profile.age > = 25) // will give you all female

const genderFemale = data.profiles.filter(profile => profile.gender === 'female' && profile.age <= 24) // All female with age less than age 24.
And so on try the JavaScript filter function

Comment: I have not yet used the filter function nor the arrow "=>". Where should those statements go? Inside the existing if-statement? edit: Now I see the const, OK just making those

Comment: The filter function will help to avoid,  for loop and you can write conditions inside the filter function. For example let allMale = data.profiles.filter(profile => profile.gender === 'male'); will give you an array of male.

Answer (score 1):

I won't go into how you can combine your `&&` and `||` smarter, since that is already answered by the [answer of Nina Scholz](/a/64413660/3982562). I would like to point out that less if-statements isn't necessary better. In my opinion the best code is understandable and readable code, so colleges and future you understand what you wrote.

```
function getResult() {
    result.innerHTML = '';

    const ageInput    = document.getElementById('age-input').value;
    const genderInput = document.getElementById('gender-input').value.toLowerCase();
    const matchesAge  = ageInput < 25
                      ? (age) => age < 25
                      : (age) => age >= 25;

    for (const profile of data.profiles) {
        if (profile.gender != genderInput) continue;
        if (!matchesAge(profile.age)) continue;

        result.innerHTML += `
            <img src='${profile.image}'>
            <h2>${profile.name}</h2>
            <p>Age: ${profile.age}</p>
            <p>${profile.description}</p>
            <hr>
            `;
    }
}
```

This solution uses the [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) (`condition ? exprIfTrue : exprIfFalse`) to create an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) that checks the if the provided age matches the criteria.

I opted to loop using [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) instead of the [standard for-loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for). Since you don't use the index to do anything other than access the current profile you might as well remove some of the visual complexity.

Lastly I use two [guard clauses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guard_%28computer_science%29) to skip to the next iteration using the [`continue`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/continue) statement. (Continue means, continue with the next iteration, meaning that the current iteration is skipped.)

Comment: Wow I love how smart this method is, and how JS in different ways are worked with. Of course these are some topics and methods that I have not yet been introduced with at my school, but I will surely save this as a "cheat-sheet" to use bits and that of if for future tasks :D Thanks!

Comment: @runEngine I assumed that you haven't handled all these topics from the way the question is formulated. That is why I've intentionally linked all newly introduced topics. There are probably even better ways to solve this, but I opted to stick to the structure of the question to not make things too confusing. I'm glad you found this answer useful.